# How to restrict users access to the bot enirely with a blacklist and unblacklist (here)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How to blacklist and whitelist users in discord.py?

(i am really new and need help i have never done anything close to this)

i tried chatgpt (im dum) and i was hoping it to work but it did work but not how i wanted it to end (cuz im dum)

(to here) and if they do try a command i want it to reply to them with a failure message.

i also want to use a command to add the blacklist and remove the blacklist.

Comment: It would be better to show us your code.  When you get a command, you can get the senders username.  You can look that up in whatever data store you want to use: SQLite, MySQL, JSON file.

Comment: i dont know how

Comment: also ill send the code

Comment: also which bit of my code? the entire thing?

Comment: if you want the entire thing add me on discord mapex#4879 cuz this has limited characters

Comment: cuz my code has 13k characters

Comment: Just make a list of the blacklisted and whitelisted names. And then, when making a request/command, simply check whether the name is in one of these lists, if so, then look in which list and deny or execute the command.

Comment: but how do i do that also i dont want usernames i want ids

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `discord.ext.commands` framework, you can easily do this by adding a [global check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.check_once):

```py
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(...)

# I recommend that you save/load your list in a json file or in a database
# For this practical example, I'm putting it directly in the code
blacklist_ids = [535159866717896726, 628120853154103316]


# This check will be executed before all your bot commands
# If it returns True the command will be executed
@bot.check_once
async def authorize(ctx: commands.Context):
    return ctx.author.id not in blacklist_ids
```

You probably also want to send an error message when the user is blacklisted. For that, you can create a custom exception and handle it in the [on_command_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) event:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(...)
blacklist_ids = [535159866717896726, 628120853154103316]


# Your custom execptions must inherit commands.CommandError
class BlackListed(commands.CommandError):
    """This error will be raised when a user who is blacklisted tries to use a command"""
    pass


@bot.check_once
async def authorize(ctx: commands.Context):
    if ctx.author.id in blacklist_ids:
        raise BlackListed
    return True


# This is a global error handler
# You can use it to handle all your command errors
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    error = getattr(error, 'original', error)  # get the original error
    if isinstance(error, BlackListed):
        await ctx.reply("You are blocked from using commands")
    elif isinstance(error, AnotherExecption):
        ...
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: is there a way to add command like -blacklist (user) and it will add the users id into the thing of the [123123123,234234234]?

Comment: Yes, but for this, you need to properly save/load your black list data. I recommend you to use a json file for this or a database.

Comment: Or MongoDB @mapex

Comment: ok ty but i dont know how could u explain?